# Vagrant and synced folders: How to set the owner to a user other than the default vagrant user?

Tags: vagrant, puppet, vagrantfile, synced-folder

I am trying to set up a development environment for a Rails 2 project within a `CoreOS` Vagrant VM that has a number of moving parts.
Once the VM is provisioned there is a `Puppet` script that installs all the bits and pieces and starts them up.

The bit that I am working on, which is on my local machine (OS X 10.10.5), is exposed in to the VM via a `synced folder` and appears in the right place in the VM with owner `vagrant` and group `vagrant`.

In order for it to work with the rest of the system the owership of that folder needs to be set to `projectx` instead.

Simply telling `Puppet` to set the permissions doesn't work. They don't change.  I've confirmed this by manually `chown`ing the files and they don't change.

I can't just set the user in the `Vagrantfile` though as, until `Puppet` has done its stuff there is no `projectx` user.

It's looking like my only solution is to hack the `Puppet` files and eliminate the use of the `projectx` user but I'd rather find a way to set the owner of the `synced folder` instead as that would be much cleaner.

How do I set the ownership of a `synced folder` to a user that is not created until after the VM has been provisioned?

Comment: Relevant error message for Google indexing: "Vagrant was unable to mount VirtualBox shared folders ... no such user"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately there are no easy ways to do that.

Common workaround is to use uid and gid in sync folder configuration. This way you can create a synced folder as a user who will be added to the system later.

```
projectx_uid = 1001
projectx_gid = 1001
config.vm.synced_folder "src/", "/srv/website",
  owner: projectx_uid, group: projectx_guid0
```

This means `projectx` should be created at the very beginning of the provisioning process so it will have predictable uid/gid

Related issue in Vagrant's tracker: https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/936

Comment: That worked fine. And I just manually specified the `gid` and `uid` in the puppet file